# Can I move getInitialProps code to componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to move the code in static getInitialProps to componentDidMount.
However, there are two parameters(component, ctx) in getInitialProps and I should use them all.
I just want to know whether I can move the code.
Thank you!

No Idea..

```
// Current
class extends App {
  public static async getInitialProps({Component, ctx}) {
     // Do Something with two parameters
  }
  .
  .
  .
}

// What I want to do
class extends App {
  public componentDidMount() {
    // Do the same thing
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInitialProps` works in both server and client side while `componentDidMount` is only for the client side.Therefore, you can't use it inside `componentDidMount`.

If you want to use data fetched in `getInitialProps` inside componentDidMount, you can return data from `getInitialProps` and use it as a `prop`.

```
class extends App{
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    //do some data fetching
    return { data };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.data)
  }
```

}